# What is this "time signature"?

Tags: notation, time-signatures, renaissance-music

[image]

Piece: Nuper rosarum Flores - Dufay

What does this "time signature" mean? I've read that it's about the taleas but I've read different stuff too, please help :)

Comment: A circle used to denote 3/4, (and maybe 3/2), which was changed to a broken circle (C) for 4/4, although with 12/4 looking like it would be from the dots, who knows?!

Comment: On an older post I was told that there were no bar lines in the Renaissance (piece is from 1437) so the bar lines are for modern composers to find their way around, thx though ^^

Answer (score 5):

This is what the Wikipedia article on the piece says.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuper_rosarum_flores

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuper_rosarum_flores]

Comment: I don't think so, these are common signs in Mensurnotation, I just still don't get why there are 4 instead of 1

Comment: So I discover!  I've modified my answer.